# What is this camera attachment

Tags: camera, equipment-identification, hotshoe

[image: i have no idea what this is]
See image above, it is a right angled bracket of some sort. It has a tripod screw on the bottom, that is adjustable left or right. It is foldable, and on the top part it has a screw-in for a tripod, like the ones you see on the cameras themselves, a hand strap, and a shoe mount (probably cold). Could someone tell me what this is? My friend said it was a gimbal, but after searching up gimbals, I can verify that that is wrong.

Comment: What are the approximate dimensions? Was it stored with a particular camera?

Answer (score 5):

Based on the description, it is a flash bracket. A flash can be mounted in the cold shoe and connected to the camera using a sync cord.

One use is to allow the use of hot shoe mounted flashes on cameras without a hot shoe. Another use is to move the flash further from the lens axis when a camera has a hot shoe to reduce red-eye and produce slightly more interesting shadows for portraits.